# How to disable processor drivers

Tags: multi-core, cpu

I have a Toshiba laptop that freezes when I plug in the AC Power cord. But I remedy this in Windows 7 by going into Safe Mode then

Control Panel > Device Manager > Processors and disable both of them.

What I am disabling is the processor driver actually thus preventing the processor from going into C or P states. The problem is, whenever the processor goes in power management or downclocks, the system freezes and shows colorful horizontal or vertical lines.

I wanted to try out Ubuntu 11.10 and I don't know how to do this in this new OS.

P.S. I've just installed Ubuntu 11.10 and I have no idea on it. I want to move to this new OS and be done with Windows. Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you should be able to do something along the lines of:

```
echo 0|sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/online
```

to disable cpu1 (cpu0 would be the first one, cpu1 next and so on).

If you wanted to disable a number of them in one line, try either this (here CPUs 1 through 7):

```
for i in $(seq 1 7); do
  echo 0|sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu$i/online
done
```

(as a one-liner this becomes: `for i in $(seq 1 7); do echo 0|sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu$i/online; done`) or:

```
echo 0|sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu{1,2,3,4,5,6,7}/online
```

Obviously some CPU needs to be operable, though. So I suggest you try to figure out what exactly causes the behavior when you plug in the power.

Also check out the pseudo-files `offline`, `online`, `possible`, `present` inside `/sys/devices/system/cpu/` as they will give you and insight which CPUs are available at all.

**Edit:** given your additional information, you might want to check whether your (Ubuntu) system has the following packages installed and then edit the details into your question so we can help: `apmd`, `toshset`, `acpid`. Use the following (replace `<package-name>` with the aforementioned):

```
dpkg -l|grep <package-name>
```

Comment: I've installed apmd.
Upgraded acpid and Toshset was already pre installed.

I've also done entering the dpkg -l|grep and all the aforementioned packages.

May I ask what next?

Comment: @FrancisDoy: I wanted to know *whether* they were installed, not that you install them. So which of them are installed then?

Comment: sorry about that ^_^ the only ones installed were acpid and toshnet.

Comment: @FrancisDoy: OK, my first attempt in that case would be to uninstall `acpid` or at least stop it (`service acpid stop`) and then try the powerplug to see whether this helps anything. But get rid of the `apmd` again first of all (`apt-get --purge remove apmd`).

Comment: still didn't work.

Comment: @FrancisDoy: I'm afraid at least I can't help in this case. Still, if it is just one of the CPUs, my answer might help in case you haven't tried (first part).

Comment: thanks for you help :) and I've already tried the first step also.. still didn't work.. damn these toshiba laptops